# Logout with Spring Security with Java configuration

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4.0.2.RELEASE with Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE.

I am unable to create a logout link (I maen what must be the value of the href attribute).

Consider :

Configuring ***DelegatingFilterProxy*** in Java with ***WebApplicationInitializer***:

```
public class SecurityWebInitializer
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

***Simple configuration class to enable web security for Spring MVC***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig
    extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.formLogin().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/spitter/").authenticated()   
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/spitter/register").authenticated().and()

            .logout().deleteCookies("remove")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password")
            .roles("USER").and().withUser("admin").password("password")
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

}
```

***Controller:***

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/spitter")
public class SpittrController {

    private SpittleRepository spittleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SpittrController(SpittleRepository spittleRepository) {

        this.spittleRepository = spittleRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showRegistrationForm() {

        return "registerForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processingRegistration(@Valid Spitter spitter, Errors errors) {

        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "registerForm";
        }

        spittleRepository.save(spitter);
        return "redirect:/spitter/" + spitter.getUserName();

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSpitterProfile(@PathVariable("username") String username,
                                     Model model) {

        Spitter spitter = spittleRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(spitter != null){
            model.addAttribute(spitter);
        }

        return "profile";
    }
}
```

***registerForm.jsp:***

```
<form method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="firstName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lastName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td><input type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}">
    </form>
```

After submission of ***registerForm.jsp***, the ***profile.jsp*** is shown to the user:

***profile.jsp:***

```
<body>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>

    <p>The time on the server is ${serverTime}.</p>

    <h1>Your Profile</h1>
    <h1><a href="/logout">Logout</a></h1>


    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><c:out value="${spitter.firstName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><c:out value="${spitter.lastName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><c:out value="${spitter.userName}" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</body>
```

When I hit

> http://localhost:8080/web/spitter/register

I am redirected to the login page. After login and submitting the form, the ***profile.jsp*** is shown in which I have included a ***Logout*** link. On clicking that, ***HTTP 404*** comes up.

I have gone through [Spring Security docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html), but they have taken ***thymeleaf*** into consideration. My is a simple JSP page.

Furthermore, I have also considered taking this into account,

> By default POST request is required to the logout url. To perform
>   logout on GET request you need:
>
> http
>         .logout()
>             .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
>
> [1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html):
>   http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html

Any suggestions?

Comment: `/logout` as URL or action in a form will only work if your application is deployed as root. You need to include the `context-root`. Use the URL tag for that `<c:url value="/logout" />` should do the trick.

Comment: @Denium:  You mean web/spitter/logout.

Comment: If `/web/spitter` is the context root of your app yes, else no... As stated use the URL tag which does that for you. (As also in the answer, which is basically correct but includes the wrong URL).

Comment: @Deinum: Thank you Denium. There was no need to include the context root since it is taken into consideration by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the your code in profile.jsp as

```
<h1><a href="#" onclick="javascript:logoutForm.submit();">logout</a></h1>

        <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout" />
        <form action="${logoutUrl}" method="post" id="logoutForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Although this answer is correct, you might elaborate a little on the why you should do this and point to relevant sections of the reference guide. Also the link is wrong it should be `/logout`.

Comment: @Balwinder: Nope, it didn't help. I got HTTP Status 404 - /web/j_spring_security_logout

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari the url link was wrong. Just edited my answer.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari What is the error you are getting now?

Comment: @BalwinderSingh: Thank you very much indeed. Thank you once again.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari Glad to help you buddy :)