# Jsp to servlet not redirecting

Tags: java, jsp

I want to redirect on clicking `submit` button on Main page to `LogoutServlet` servlet, but instead servlet 404 not found error page is showing up. I have also updated web.xml file. I have no idea what is the problem here.

> MainPage.jsp

```
<form action="LogoutServlet" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="LogOut"></input></form>
```

> LogoutServlet.java

```
package com.lfg.fc.web.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

 public class LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public LogoutServlet() {
    super();

}

 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}


   public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
   response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doPost(request,response);
    }


     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
     response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Logout.jsp");
    HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
    rd.forward(request, response);
    }

     }
```

Comment: Can you past servlet mapper code from web.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the servlet information in `web.xml` like this:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.lfg.fc.web.servlets.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Then call your servlet on form action like this :

```
<form action="/LogoutServlet" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="LogOut"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: So what is your problem could you clarify that in your question

Comment: My jsp page action methods are going to a controller page. "@RequestMapping" is used in the controller for all the linked pages. Can you tell me the Logout Code using "@requestMapping" {@RequestMapping(value = "/Logout.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558370/logout-with-spring-security-with-java-configuration.

Comment: Like used in this link having controller